# Exspose react app on public ip to the internet using linux vm ubunut

Tags: reactjs, linux, nginx, virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to expose an app to the internet on my computers public ip. Therefore I have set up ubuntu 20.04 on Windows VM and installed ngnix serer. In addition to that I ve opened ubuntu firewall to receive trafic on port 80 and 443 and configured ngnix server:

```
   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app.com                   
       server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       root /var/www/app.com/html/dist;
       index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
      
       location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    } 
  }
```

Until now when i visit localhost:80 indeed it returns my app in the browser. Now how would i achieve to return the app when i visit to my public ip? which would also make it accessable from the internet.

Right now when ever i enter my public ip in the browser it makes nothing. thanks